# How to send HTTP Request - PUT to different path concurrently with Jmeter?

Tags: concurrency, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I have a volume test to test response time for sending PUT method to different locations concurrently up to 100-200 locations. I'm using jmeter and I'm just wondering if there is a way to achieve in jmeter?

**Test - HTTP PUT same file to different locations concurrently (up to 100-200 locations).**

Example - It is to send below 5 requests (up to 200) at the time time to different location.

```
1. Put /location1/object1 File 1
2. Put /location2/object2 File 1
3. Put /location3/object3 File 1
4. Put /location4/object4 File 1
5. Put /location4/object4 File 1
```

I've been tried loop and while controller with CSV data set but it seems like they are sending one after one from CSV instead of concurrently. The only solution I can think of is to create up to 100 - 200 thread groups to run the test plan. If I do create 100 - 200 thread groups, I'm not certain that will impact my PC?

Below is my current Test Plan.

```
Test Plan
    HTTP Request Default
    HTTP Header Manager
    Thread Group 
        + Get Service
            Get URL
        + While Controller
            Put Method
                 Put {PATH from CSV} File 1
            CSV Data Set Config
                 {5 paths in CSV}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use specify the thread num to be 400 in thread group and use `threadNum()` function

Answer (score 0):

To run all request from csv file concurrently, you can use [CSVRead function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#_CSVRead)